# LINQ dynamic query for entity framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have two Guid collections:

```
List<Guid> statuses;
List<Guid> priorities;
```

How to make the following query:

```
var result = context.Activity.Where(a => 
    (a.StatusID == statuses[0] || a.StatusID == statuses[1] || ... || a.StatusID == statuses[n]) &&
    (a.PriorityID == priorities[0] || a.PriorityID == priorities[1] || ... || a.PriorityID  == priorities[m]))
```

Collections could be empty and in this case we shouldn't add an appropriate 'AND' condition. How to do such dynamic query?

**UPDATE**

Hmm, imagine I need something like this:

```
List<Func<Activity, bool>> conds = new List<Func<Activity, bool>>();

var result = context.Activity.Where(conds[0] || (conds[1] && conds[2]))
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First answer based on question**
Selects only those `Activity` objects of which the `StatusID` is in `statusses` and the `PriorityID` is in `priorities`. Obviously if the collections are empty none of the `Activity` objects will match the condition.

```
var result = context.Activity.Where(a => 
    statuses.Contains(a.StatusID) && priorities.Contains(a.PriorityID));
```

**Alternative answer based on @Don Tomato's comment**
There must have been a misunderstanding based on the way you formulated the question. However, I think what you want is to add conditions to an `IQueryable` as required.

```
List<Func<Activity, bool>> conditions = new List<Func<Activity, bool>>();
// add conditions to the list
// for eaxmple:
// conditions.add(a => statuses.Contains(a.StatusID));
// or 
// conditions.add(a => a.Name == "Don Tomato");

IQueryable query = context.Activity.AsQueryable();
foreach (Func<Activity, bool> condition in conditions)
   query = query.Where(condition);

List<Activity> result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Agreed, I missed the obvious dammit!

Comment: @DonTomato, This should send an SQL `[StatusID] IN (<statusID>, ...)` to your database server.

Comment: Good answer, thanks!, but this is not quite what I expected. Suppose I'm going to design a very complex query, where, depending on certain conditions, will add or remove different AND and OR conditions. I would like to see a way to construct a query like in Lego constructions. I need to build the filter expression step-by-step with an 'and/or' combination of each part, instead of inventing ingenious and elegant way to solve a simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain where clauses together like this and the end result is that they will be anded together:

```
var query = context.Activity.Where(o => <condition1>);

if (2ndconditionrequired)
{
    query = query.where(o => <condition2>);
}

query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this:

```
var result = context.Activity;

if (statuses != null && statuses.Count > 0)
{
    result = results.Where(a => 
        a.StatusID == statuses[0] || a.StatusID == statuses[1] || ... || a.StatusID == statuses[n];
}

if (priorities != null && priorities.Count > 0)
{
    result = results.Where(a => 
        a.PriorityID == priorities[0] || a.PriorityID == priorities[1] || ... || a.PriorityID  == priorities[m]);
}

result.ToList(); // The query won't be executed until here.
```

But I guess what you really want to do is as @Bazzz answered.